# Add column to existing table set default to sysdate for existing records and tomorrows date for new entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am learning SQL while I found below task,

Insert  a new column StartDate in existing table and for the existing records should have sysdate and for new entries should have tomorrow's date.

until now I did

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE());
```

from here I unable to go forward i am thinking the task itself is not correct am i thinking correct or can we perform this task pls anyone help me out.

Comment: The task's requirement isn't clear.

Comment: So on INSERT, the date should always be the current date +1 day?

Comment: You would need to first add the column as nullable. Then update the existing rows to whatever value. Then change the column to be NOT NULL and add the default (which if it should be tomorrow would dateadd(day, 1, getdate()).

Comment: Good catch on null @SeanLange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read Sean’s comment on making the column `NULLABLE`. Then, you'd change your command to:

The default should be `dateadd(day,1,getdate())`. This would work for future inserts where you don't specify a value on insert.

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD StartDate DATETIME NULL DEFAULT (DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()));
```

For the other rows, you simply need to update then once you have made this table change.

```
update table test
set StartDate = getdate()
where StartDate is null --which is every row that wasn't inserted after the change
```

Then, alter the column to make it `NOT NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE test
ALTER COLUMN StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ADD StartDate2 DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATEADD(DAY, 1,GETDATE()));
```